# Changing output from text of date to useable format in bash

Tags: bash

I'm not really sure how to phrase this question, but here goes:

I have a command which returns the date of last connection to an app in the format of 'adDateLastConnected: Thursday, August 23, 2018 at 12:00:07 PM'. I managed to strip out the first part, and only display the date, but I'd like to view this in a more standard date format (like 08-23-2018 12:00:07 PM).

Is this a trivial thing, or is it far more complicated than I suspect? I'm not sure of how deep my ignorance goes :-)

Answer (score 3):

GNU date is pretty good about interpreting human style date formats:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(date --version) != *GNU* ]]
then
  echo "Sorry, this script only works with GNU date." >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Make locale independent
export LC_ALL=C

# Strip the " at " part
x="${1// at / }"

echo "ISO time:  $(date --iso-8601=seconds -d "$x")"
echo "Unix time: $(date -d "$x" +%s)"
```

Example:

```
$ ./myscript "Thursday, August 23, 2018 at 12:00:07 PM"
ISO time:  2018-08-23T12:00:07-07:00
Unix time: 1535050807
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not difficult. You can format with sed or gawk (awk), any one of theses will do the job for you.

An example with AWK:

```
awk '
   BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," } 
   { split($3, date, /\//)
     $3 = date[3] "-" date[2] "-" date[1]
     print $0 
   }
' infile
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. Try it with `Thursday, August 23, 2018 at 12:00:07 PM` as the input. You're trying to split on `/`, but the input doesn't contain any slashes.

Comment: was a exemple snippet, this code snippet can be change for his need.

Comment: Just splitting isn't enough, though. You have to translate month names to numbers as well.